# Python: matching data to existing names

Tags: python, similarity

When users tried to use search bar, there might be lots of typo error. For example, I have a data set which is about mobile brand names.

```
nokia, nakia, nokea,mokia
samsung, samsumg, zamsung
sony, SONY, sonii, ソニー
htc, hTc, hta
```

I already set them in different categories, and use fuzzywuzzy to calculate a similarity score between two strings.

```
fuzz.ratio("sony", "ソニー")  #0
fuzz.ratio("sony", "sany")   #75
```

"ソニー" is actually "sony" in Japanese, but it cannot recognize it. How can I set it to make them have high similarity?

Also, if there's a new string called "somy", is there a possible way to let it categorized with "sony"? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you're going to need a romanization library that can generate the various Latin-script equivalents of all strings in other scripts, or maybe even a more general transliteration library (so a katakana search can match English words). Unfortunately, SO is not a good place to ask for library recommendations. Maybe go to python.org's Community section, and see if there's a relevant-looking mailing list, and if not try the general python-list or the IRC channel.

Comment: Actually, first do a PyPI search and see if there's anything obvious that you can try out; you may find something without needing help.